# Working with multiple cores and sparse matrices in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow, parallel-foreach

I am working on a project that requires large matrices with a larger number of zeros. Unfortunately, as some of these matrices can have more than 1e10 elements, working with the "standard" R matrices is not an option, due to RAM constraints. Also, I need to work on multiple cores, as the computation can take quite a long time and really shouldn't.

So far, I have been working with the `foreach` package, and converted the results (which come in standard matrices) to sparse matrices afterwards. I can't help but think that there must be a smarter way.

Here is a minimal example of what I have been doing so far:

```
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(8)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

Mat <- foreach(j=1:length(lambda), .combine='cbind') %dopar% { 
  replicate(iter, rpois(n=1, lambda[j]))
}
Mat <- Matrix(Mat, sparse=TRUE)
stopCluster(cl)
```

The lambdas are all quite small, so that only every 5th element or so is different from zero, making it sensible to store the results in a sparse matrix.

Unfortunately, it has now become necessary to increase the number of iterations from 1e6 to at least 1e7, so that the matrix that is produced by the `foreach` loop is too large to be stored on 8GB of RAM. What I now want to do is split up the tasks into steps that each have 1e6 iterations, and combine these into a single, sparse matrix.

I now have the following as an idea:

```
library(Matrix)
library(snow)

cl <- makeSOCKcluster(8)

iter <- 1e6

steps <- 1e5
numsteps <- iter / steps

draws <- function(x, lambda, steps){
  replicate(n=steps, rpois(n=1, lambda=lambda))
}

for(i in 1:numsteps){
  Mat <- Matrix(0, nrow=steps, ncol=96, sparse=TRUE)

  Mat <- Matrix(
    parApply(cl=cl, X=Mat, MARGIN=2, FUN=draws, lambda=0.2, steps=steps)
    , sparse = TRUE)

  if(!exists("fullmat")) fullmat <- Mat else fullmat <- rBind(fullmat, Mat)

  rm(Mat)   
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

It works fine, but I had to fix lambda to some value. For my application, I need the values in the ith row to come from a poisson distribution with mean equal to the ith element of the lambda vector. This obviously worked fine in the `foreach` loop., but I have yet to find a way to make it work in an apply loop.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to have the apply function "know" on which row it is operating and pass a corresponding argument to a function?
2. Is there a way to work with foreach and sparse matrices without the need of creating a standard matrix and converting it into a sparse one in the next step?
3. If none of the above, is there a way for me to manually assign tasks to slave processes of R - that is, could I specifically tell a process to work on column 1, another to work on column 2 and so on, each creating a sparse vector and only combining these in the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem.

In my case, I am able to define a unique ID for each of the columns, and can address the parameters by that. The following code should illustrate what I mean:

```
library(snow)
library(Matrix)

iter <- 1e6
steps <- 1e5

# define a unique id
SZid <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)

# in order to have reproducible code, generate random parameters
SZlambda <- replicate(runif(n=1, min=0, max=.5))
SZmu <- replicate(runif(n=1, min=10, max=15))
SZsigma <- replicate(runif(n=1, min=1, max=3))

cl <- makeSOCKcluster(8)
clusterExport(cl, list=c("SZlambda", "SZmu", "SZsigma"))

numsteps <- iter / steps

MCSZ <- function(SZid, steps){ # Monte Carlo Simulation 
  lambda <- SZlambda[SZid]; mu <- SZmu[SZid]; sigma <- SZsigma[SZid];

  replicate(steps, sum(rlnorm(meanlog=mu, sdlog=sigma, 
                              n = rpois(n=1, lambda))
                       ))
}

for (i in 1:numsteps){
  Mat <- Matrix(
    parSapply(cl, X=SZid, FUN=MCSZ, steps=steps), sparse=TRUE)

  if(!exists("LossSZ")) LossSZ <- Mat else LossSZ <- rBind(LossSZ, Mat)
  rm(Mat)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

The trick is to apply the function not over the matrix, but over a vector of unique ids that line up with the indices of the parameters.